# Are block-transposes of matrices with commuting blocks similar?

Tags: linear-algebra, block-matrices, transpose

Suppose $A$ is an $nm \times nm$ block matrix over some field, with $n^2$ blocks each of size $m \times m$. Suppose further that the blocks commute. Let $A^{BT}$ denote the "block transpose" of $A$, namely the $nm \times nm$ block matrix whose $(j,i)$ block is the $(i,j)$ block of $A$. That is, the positions of the blocks have been transposed, but not the blocks themselves.

Is $A$ similar to $A^{BT}$?

If $m=1$, the answer is yes. I can show that $A$ and $A^{BT}$ have the same minimal and characteristic polynomials in general.

For example, suppose $A, B, C, D$ are commuting $2 \times 2$ matrices. Is it necessarily the case that
\begin{align*}
  \begin{pmatrix}
    A & B \\
    C & D
  \end{pmatrix}
  \sim
  \begin{pmatrix}
    A & C \\
    B & D
  \end{pmatrix}?
\end{align*}

Comment: It is easy to see that the answer is yes in the case that $A,B,C,D$ are each diagonalizable, but I'm not sure about the more general case. I suspect that the answer is yes and that this can be shown using the simultaneous triangularizability of $A,B,C,D$.

Comment: @BenGrossmann What's your argument in the diagonalizable case? I had considered simultaneous diagonalizations/triangularizations but hadn't gotten anywhere.

Comment: In light of @user1551's counterexample, I would be interested in sufficient additional conditions on the blocks for this property to hold.

Comment: Just for the record, this $A$ can be interpreted as an element of $M_n\otimes M_m$ via Kronecker product. This block transpose is commonly called the partial transpose of the left side of this tensor. It is a well known fact that the partial transpose does not preserve the spectrum of a matrix.

Comment: @Daniel Thanks for the keyword. When the blocks commute, the characteristic polynomial is the determinant of the Leibniz formula applied to the blocks. The Leibniz formula is the same for the original or the block-transpose, so their characteristic polynomials agree and they have the same spectrum in this case.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When $m\ge4$, the answer is "no". Consider $m=2k$ and $A,B,C,D\in M_{2k}(\mathbb F)$ such that
$$
A=\pmatrix{0&X\\ 0&0},
\ B=\pmatrix{0&Y\\ 0&0},
\ C=\pmatrix{0&Z\\ 0&0},
\ D=\pmatrix{0&W\\ 0&0}
$$
for some $X,Y,Z,W\in M_k(\mathbb F)$. Clearly $A,B,C,D$ commute, because the product of any two of them is zero. However, when $k\ge2$, we have
$$
\text{rank of }\pmatrix{A&B\\ C&D}=\text{rank of }\pmatrix{X&Y\\ Z&W}\ne\text{rank of }\pmatrix{X&Z\\ Y&W}=\text{rank of }\pmatrix{A&C\\ B&D}
$$
in general. Therefore the matrix on the left is not always similar to its blockwise transpose. E.g. let $k=2$ and $\{X,Z,Y,W\}$ be the standard basis of $M_k(\mathbb F)$. Then
$$
\text{rank of }\left(\begin{array}{cc|cc}1&0&0&1\\ 0&0&0&0\\ \hline0&0&0&0\\ 1&0&0&1\end{array}\right)
=2\ne4=
\text{rank of }\left(\begin{array}{cc|cc}1&0&0&0\\ 0&0&1&0\\ \hline0&1&0&0\\ 0&0&0&1\end{array}\right).
$$

Answer (score 3):

In response to the comments on the question: the statement will hold if $A,B,C,D$ are diagonalizable.

Suppose that $A,B,C,D$ are diagoanlizable. Because they commute, they are simultaneously diagonalizable, which is to say that there exists an invertible $S$ such that
$$
\Lambda_A = S^{-1}AS, \quad \Lambda_B = S^{-1}BS, \quad \Lambda_C = S^{-1}CS,  \quad \Lambda_D = S^{-1}DS
$$
are all diagonal. We note that
$$
\pmatrix{S \\ & S}^{-1} \pmatrix{A&B\\C&D}\pmatrix{S\\&S} = \pmatrix{\Lambda_A & \Lambda_B \\ \Lambda_C & \Lambda_D}.
$$
On the other hand, this matrix is similar to its transpose. Putting these together gives us that
$$
\pmatrix{A&B\\C&D} \sim \pmatrix{\Lambda_A & \Lambda_C\\ \Lambda_B & \Lambda_D}.
$$
Finally, we have
$$
\pmatrix{S \\ & S} \pmatrix{\Lambda_A&\Lambda_C\\\Lambda_B&\Lambda_D}\pmatrix{S\\&S}^{-1} = \pmatrix{A & C\\ B& D},
$$
which means that we have
$$
\pmatrix{A & B\\C&D} \sim \pmatrix{A & C\\B&D},
$$
which was what we wanted.

Comment: The implicit argument used in your proof is the fact that the transposition can be performed by first computing the block transposition and then the transposition of each block. Now if each block is already symmetric (diagonal in your case) then there is no need for the second step. So the transposition and the block transposition coincide in this case. Notice that the blocks don't need to commute, if they are symmetric.